# I am having trouble with an array in a json file and appending it into html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the Json file I am trying to get the thumbnail image and subheadline in to a bootstrap card by appending it.

```
       {
        "meta": {
            "domain": "url is private",
        },
        "response": {
            "count": 50,
            "result": [{
                        "listImage": {
                            "thumbnail": "url is private",
                            "large": "url is private",
                            "tile": "url is private",
                            "mobile": "url is private",
                            "raw": {
                                "size": {
                                    "w": 1180,
                                    "h": 746
                                },
                                "focal_point": {
                                    "yoffset": "50",
                                    "xoffset": "50"
                                },
                                "url": "url is private",
                            },
                            "source": "url is private",
                            "portrait": "url is private",
                            "landscape": "url is private",
                        },
                        "url": "url is private",
                        "brand": "nets",
                        "headline": "Kevin Durant and Brooklyn Nets Hit an Offensive Rhythm",
                        "subheadline": "Over last nine games, Nets averaging 122.3 points with 124.5 offensive rating while shooting 53.4 percent",
                        "changed": "2022-03-22T16:22:35-04:00",
                        "teaser": "Kevin Durant has averaged 37.5 points on 68.4 percent shooting in his last two games.",
                        "apiUri": "/2/nets/article/a94cbda5-292b-418a-959a-b4f12ae610c5"
                    },
```

Below is the JavaScript I wrote to get the Json file and I can see the data in the console but I an getting tripped up on the array of 5O cause in the console it come up at 0: 1: 2: etc.

```
    $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "the url goes here",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                console.log(data);
                $(".row").append("<div class='card shadow-sm'>" + "<img src=" + data.result[0 - 49].listImage.thumbnail + "alt=" + response.result.title + "width='500' height='600'>" + "<div class='card-body'>" + "<h5 class='card-title'>" + response.result.title + "</h5>" + "<p class='card-text'>" + response.result.subheadline + "</p>" + "<div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>" + "<small class='text-muted'>" + response.result.value + "</small>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does `data.result[0 - 49]` mean?

Comment: That is part of where I am going wrong.  I don't know what to put in the below to get the Thumbnail to appear.
 + data.result[0-49].listImage.thumbnail +

Comment: If `data` is an object and `result` is an array maybe `$.each(data.response.result...`. And then you can use `value.listImage.thumbnail` instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on `data.result[0 - 49]`? I still don't understand it.

Comment: Are you wanting all 50 or just one?  If all then you'll need a loop wrapping `$(".row").append` - if it's just one then pick a single number, eg `data.result[0]` for the first.

Comment: I will try a couple of these suggestions and I will get back with the results. I do want all 50 so I will loop it. I just want to get one to show up first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here is a page where I have the test: https://spthegeekout.com/test/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "URL GOES HERE",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.response.result, function(index, info) {
        console.log(info);
        $(".row").append("<div class='card shadow-sm'>" + 
            "<img src=" + info.listImage.thumbnail + "alt=" + info.brand + "width='500' height='600'>" + "<div class='card-body'>" + 
                "<h5 class='card-title'>" + info.headline + "</h5>" + 
                "<p class='card-text'>" + info.subheadline + "</p>" + 
                "<div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>" + 
                    "<small class='text-muted'>" + info.teaser + 
                        "</small>" + 
                        "</div>" + 
                        "</div>" + 
                        "</div>" + 
                        "</div>");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `index` for accessing each element of the list by writing `data.result[index]`. `value` is the whole object (same as `data.result[index]`) so you cannot add it into div, it will result in (Object object).
So, eather you use `data.result[index].someProperty` or `value.someProperty`

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "the url goes here",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        console.log(data);
        $(".row").append("<div class='card shadow-sm'>" + "<img src=" + data.result[index].listImage.thumbnail + "alt=" + response.result[index].brand + "width='500' height='600'>" + "<div class='card-body'>" + "<h5 class='card-title'>" + response.result[index].headline + "</h5>" + "<p class='card-text'>" + response.result.subheadline + "</p>" + "<div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>" + "<small class='text-muted'>" + response.result[index].teaser + "</small>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This solution does not work I get the following error.

index.html:241 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'meta')
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.html:241:29)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:2623)
    at Object.success (index.html:238:9)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:27457)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:28202)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:77651)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:79907)

Comment: try changing it to `.success: function(data) {
data = data.response.result;
      $.each(data, function(index, value) ....`